# Grid problems on resize

Tags: html, css, grid-layout

having this,

`Grid:` http://jsfiddle.net/f5h08fc6/2/

How could I achieve to show images without deforming. I've tried with

```
max-width:100%;
height:auto;
```

but then it the grid show blanks spaces when resizing the window.

I cannot find a solution for showing the grid correctly and without blank spaces on the grid. I will appreciate a solution involving just css if possible.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Looks like a mess :$ Ever tried cleaning it up? >< Btw; maybe you can use something like [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)?

Comment: it's really is a mess...can't you just use jquery plugin? http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-grid-plugin/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option would probably be to play around with background-position, background-size and object-fit object-position css. Object-fit / object-position is not supported by internet explorer, but if you set this the stretching won't occur, but to get the image positioned how you want you'll have to user object-position to individually position them:

```
.secreto2 img {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    object-fit:cover;
    object-position:50%;
}
```

Also remove the absolute positioning from .secreto2:after, otherwise the fit gets screwed up on hover.

http://jsfiddle.net/benneb10/f5h08fc6/6/

Comment: Hi @Benneb10, thanks for your answer. This almost fits my solution but now the pictures are cut... is there any way to solve that detail??

Comment: You can use object-fit:contain, but it's going to leave huge gaps in your design. Using object-fit:cover fills the desired width:100% and height:100%, however you can choose how they're cut and positioned with object-position and specifying px to be moved. I would honestly look more into background-position and background-size so it has better browser compatibility, but you may need to change your html and css a bit more.